# Grid column Start and end without specifying start or end

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a class, lets call it `.col3` and it is a grid item inside a div with the class of `.container`

Container has `grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%`

I want the class `.col3` to span 3 columns. I know that normally I could use:

```
.col3{
   grid-column-start: 1;
   grid-column-end: 4;
}
```

but that does not specify the times when I want it to start on col 2 and go to the end. Is there a universal "make this class span 3 columns" that I could use?

Comment: `grid-column-end: -1;`, or `grid-colunm; span 3`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a universal "make this class span 3 columns" that I could use?

## Yes

```
grid-column: span 3;
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column)

> `span`
>
> **Contributes a grid span to the grid item’s placement such that the corresponding edge of the grid item’s grid area is n lines from the opposite edge.**

```css
.col3 {
  grid-column: span 3;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.col2 {
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col2"></div>
  <div class="col3"></div>
  <div>
```

Alternatively, specifying the end as `-1` will span to the last grid-column track.

Comment: I'm a bit new to css grid, what does the `grid-columns: 2 / span 2` mean? more specifically the 2 / span 2 part

Comment: @HaveProblemsEveryday `2 / span 2` -> `start at line 2 / span 2 columns`. A 4 column css-grid has 5 horizontal lines: `1 or -5`- column 1 - `2 or -4` -  column 2 - `3 or -3` - column 3 - `4 or -2` - column 4 - `5 or -1`. The first number 2 , means line 2 (which equals -4 in this case), which is the line between 1st and 2nd column.

Comment: @HaveProblemsEveryday alternativly you can use `grid-columns:  2 /  4;` instead. This will amke the element start at line 2 and end at line 4. This equals the same as `2 / span 2`